# Is it good to pass CamelCase controller name in Cakephp URL?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Sorry for this basic question

I have a controller named "UserProfiles" it contain a function named "view". 
But when a user login i redirecting to that view method.
I using the following code :
1.) $this->redirect('/UserProfiles/view');
and i have other option 
2.) $this->redirect('/user_profiles/view');

My Output: http://www.sample.com/UserProfiles/view Or 
http://www.sample.com/user_profiles/view

My doubt is which is correct standard to use in cakephp, and which of these 2 option will helpful for SEO friendly url ?

Comment: What would be wrong with just `'profiles'`?

Comment: I need to know which is the cakephp standard to pass in urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CakePHP convention is that you use *underscored* and *lowercase* in your urls.

See: http://book.cakephp.org/view/904/Controller-Conventions#URL-Considerations-for-Controller-Names-905

Comment: However, if you want it to show something different (such as `/account`, `/profiles`, etc), you should [define your own routes](http://book.cakephp.org/view/948/Defining-Routes) for this instead of renaming your classes.